# @ControllerAdvice does not map to the error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a REST service, where i need to send appropriate status codes with the custom json response, which explains the reason for the error.

I have @Controller class which exposes a service /test and while hitting the service, I am throwing a custom exception (extends Exception class)

I have a @ControllerAdvice class which handles the exception. However, whenever i get error i don't get the json response, instead the stack trace is printed.

Checked the blogs and tried the solutions. However could not get it resolved.

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.test")
public class ResponseExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{


    @ExceptionHandler(value= {MyException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(code=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<MyResponse> commonServiceException(MyException ex) {
        MyResponse errors = new MyResponse();

        errors.setTimeStamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        errors.setErrorCode(ex.getErrorCode());
        errors.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
        errors.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getReasonPhrase());
        errors.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

SERVICE

```
@Controller
....
public class test{
..
        @GET
    @Path("/test")
    //@ExceptionHandler(value= {MyException.class})
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public  String test() throws MyException{
          throw new MyException("123", "message");

    }
```

context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package=" com.test">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" />
    </context:component-scan>
```

Expected  : JSON Response

Actual : Type Exception Report

Message Service currently unavailable. Error Code : Application Error. Error

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

com.test.MyException: Service currently unavailable. Error Code : Application Error..............................

Comment: are you directly throwing Myexception? or there is another class which is handling this exception and controlleradvice is not getting Myexception class.

Comment: I just added this for testing purpose..Actual business logic is another class will throw this exception

Comment: can you show the another class? because whenever you will handle this exception by another exception you can not hit controller advice class.

Comment: I have not prepared the other class yet.. as I was trying to get this working. I could not understand your statement "whenever you will handle this exception by another exception you can not hit controller advice class" Can you please explain me ? Is the above code not correct ?

Comment: No i thought there is another class which you haven't written here.

Comment: can you remove your base package and try again?

Comment: Yes, tried removing that. Also tried using RestController and RestControllerAdvice annotation. Seems does nt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because I was mixing up Jersey and Spring Framework. After doing necessary spring servlet configurations in web.xml and using @RequestMapping the issue is resolved.